# mean and covariance of a random process

Tags: random-variables, random-walk

I'm looking at an example from a book I'm reading,
[image]

How does it formulate the mean? 
I am thinking $$E[X[n]] = \sum\limits^\infty_{-\infty} X[n]P[X[n]] =\\
\sum\limits^\infty_{n=-\infty} X[n = even] \frac{1}{2} + X[n = even] \frac{1}{2} + X[n = odd] \frac{9}{10} + X[n = odd] \frac{1}{10} \\
= \sum\limits^\infty_{-\infty} \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{9}{10}-3\frac{1}{10} = 0$$
Does this formulation look right? I'm confused when X[n] can be probabilistically assigned values.

Comment: What does $X[n]$ mean? Did you mean $X_n$?

Comment: @WillM. Yes, I think that makes it easier to write.

Comment: The formulae you wrote does not make sense to me. $\mathbf{E}(X_n)$ is clearly zero for $n$ even and it is $\dfrac{1}{3} \times \dfrac{9}{10} - 3 \times \dfrac{1}{10} = 0$ for $n$ odd.

Comment: It seems like you are thinking of $X$ as the random variable. That is not correct, $X_n$ is a random variable, $X$ is a "random sequence."

Comment: @WillM. Ah, I see, n is the condition. That makes sense now. But I think the problem states that $X_n$ is a random sequence though, maybe $X_n[k]$ is a random variable. The notation of $m_X(n)$ is also confusing with the conditional n.

Comment: Ok, stop using $X[k]$ because that IS confusing. For a random sequence $X$ we can define a function $m_X$ such that $m_X(n) = \mathbf{E}(X_n).$

Comment: @WillM.  you are right, I think it makes sense now. For the discrete case, $X_n$ denotes the elements of the sequence, but it's like $X(t)$ that also denotes the sequence in the context of $E(X_n)$.